# applying vlookup to every element of pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, numpy, dataframe, apply

I have two dataframes, one of which is source(src), and the other one is the destination(dest)

```
dest.tail()
Out[166]: 
Item             AJ   AM   AO   AR   BA   BO  BR  BU   BY   CA ...  TJ   TK   TR  
time                                                       ...                 
    2020-06-26  3.5  4.5  5.5  7.5  4.5  7.5   7 NaN  7.0  5.5 ...   7  7.5  3.5   
    2020-06-29  3.5  4.5  5.5  7.5  4.5  7.5   7 NaN  7.0  5.5 ...   7  7.5  3.5   
    2020-06-30  3.5  4.5  5.5  7.5  4.5  7.5   7 NaN  7.0  5.5 ...   7  7.5  3.5   
    2020-07-01  3.5  4.5  5.5  1.5  4.5  7.5   7 NaN  2.5  5.5 ...   7  7.5  3.5   
    2020-07-02  3.5  4.5  5.5  1.5  4.5  7.5   7 NaN  2.5  5.5 ...   7  7.5  3.5


src.tail()
Out[167]: 
                  1.00      1.25      1.50      1.75   ...  10.00     10.25  
time                                                                     
    2020-06-29  0.153556  0.159041  0.162370  0.164580 ... 0.643962  0.658646   
    2020-06-30  0.156180  0.159280  0.161534  0.163746 ... 0.660171  0.675189   
    2020-07-01  0.156947  0.163433  0.168326  0.171734 ... 0.687046  0.701364   
    2020-07-02  0.152465  0.153910  0.154862  0.155750 ... 0.676183  0.690475   
    2020-07-03  0.154169  0.153923  0.154868  0.155751 ... 0.676537  0.690816
```

For each value in dest, i want to replace it with a value in the src table, which has same index, and same column name as itself.

e.g. Value for AJ on '2020-06-26' in the dest table right now is 3.5. I want to replace it with value in src table corresponding to index '2020-06-26' and column = 3.5

I was thinking of using applymap, but it doesnt seem to have a concept of index.

```
dest.applymap(lambda x: src.loc[x.index][x]).tail()
AttributeError: ("'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'index'", u'occurred at index AJ')
```

I then tried using apply and it worked like this:

```
dest1 = dest.replace(0,np.nan).fillna(1)  # 0 and nan are not in src.columns
df= dest1.apply(lambda x: [src[col].loc[row] for row, col in zip(x.index,x)], axis=0).tail()
```

2 questions on this:

1. Is there a better solution to this instead of doing a list comprehension within apply?
2. Is there a better way of handling values in dest that are not in src.columns (like 0 and nan) so the output is nan when that's the case?

Comment: please don't upload images: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples